# Python missing library when submitted to queue

Tags: cluster-computing

I am trying to submit a python job to the queue on an SGE cluster with scientific linux os.

I keep getting the error:

ImportError: libg2c.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When the script uses numpy.

The library doesn't exist on any of the slave nodes and seems to only be installed locally on the head node. I have full access to this cluster but I'm relatively inexperienced at cluster management.

I have tried:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path_to_lib>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

but I get the same error.

Is there a way to use this python without needing to install it on all the nodes?

If the only way is to roll this python on to all the other nodes what is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try specifying _directory_ of library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or the library path itself? Did you try LD_PRELOAD for the library file?

Comment: It was the directory: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was deceptively simple. I had been using the extract command in the terminal. Instead I included

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

in the module file. Now when I load the module the libraries are loaded with it and everything works fine.

I'm not sure why this works but hopefully this will help someone else.

Ben